# How to fix the error "Cannot iterate over a shape with unknown rank."

Tags: python, neural-network, sequential

I am working on a Digital Twin of a battery, but when I use the predict function of Sequential model class, I keep getting this error.

' ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "sequential" (type Sequential).

Cannot iterate over a shape with unknown rank.

I am kinda new to Python too.
Here's the block of code

```
  cycles = np.arange(168,500,1)
  temperature = dfb['Temperature_measured'].iloc[167]
  time = dfb['Time'].iloc[167]
  K = 0.13
  L_e = 1-e**(-K*cycles*temperature/time)
  X_in_e = -(L_e*dfb['Capacity'].iloc[0:1].values[0]) + 
  dfb['Capacity'].iloc[0:1].values[0]
  print(tf.shape(L_e))
  print(tf.rank(L_e))
  C_twin_e = X_in_e + model.predict(X_in_e).reshape(-1)
```

Output:

```
  tf.Tensor([332], shape=(1,), dtype=int32)
  tf.Tensor(1, shape=(), dtype=int32)
```

I think the cause of the problem is L_e because it's shape is unknown or something.
If someone can help me, it'd be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix, the predict() function accepts numpy arrays,tensors etc. So  just did this

```
tensor1 = tf.convert_to_tensor(X_in_e)
C_twin_e = X_in_e + model.predict(tensor1).reshape(-1)
```

This solved the problem for me.